# Why is this bitbake package not included in my image, if it's a runtime dependency of another package which is included?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm building a systemd-based image with Yocto I've run into a problem where update-rc.d (which is needed by a systemd sysv wrapper) is not present in that image.

I can confirm that update-rc.d is listed as a runtime dependency of systemd:

(see towards the end of the first line of this output)

```
$ bitbake systemd -e | grep "^RDEPENDS"
RDEPENDS:systemd=" kmod dbus util-linux-mount util-linux-umount udev (= 1:250.4-r0) systemd-udev-rules util-linux-agetty util-linux-fsck systemd-serialgetty volatile-binds ldconfig libnss-myhostname      pam-plugin-unix     pam-plugin-loginuid     pam-plugin-keyinit  systemd-compat-units update-rc.d systemd-vconsole-setup"
RDEPENDS:systemd-bash-completion="bash-completion"
RDEPENDS:systemd-conf=" update-rc.d"
RDEPENDS:systemd-dev="systemd (= 1:250.4-r0)"
RDEPENDS:systemd-doc=" "
RDEPENDS:systemd-initramfs="systemd"
RDEPENDS:systemd-kernel-install=" bash"
RDEPENDS:systemd-staticdev="systemd-dev (= 1:250.4-r0)"
RDEPENDS:udev-hwdb=" udev"
```

And systemd is obviously included in my image because I can see it working. Also inspecting my image manifest confirms that systemd has been included in the image.

```
$ grep -n systemd tmp/deploy/images/<arch>/<image_name>.manifest
283:libsystemd-shared cortexa55 1:250.4-r0
284:libsystemd0 cortexa55 1:250.4-r0
394:systemd cortexa55 1:250.4-r0
395:systemd-compat-units cortexa55 1.0-r29
396:systemd-conf txrz_g2l0 1:1.0-r0
397:systemd-extra-utils cortexa55 1:250.4-r0
398:systemd-serialgetty txrz_g2l0 1.0-r5
399:systemd-udev-rules cortexa55 1:250.4-r0
400:systemd-vconsole-setup cortexa55 1:250.4-r0
```

And yet, update-rc.d keeps not being included in the resultant image. The package name (i.e. update-rc.d) is missing from the manifest and the actual script file it's supposed to provide is missing from the image rootfs.

Why is this happening and what can I do to debug why this runtime dependency is missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the package was missing because the base image class added it to a `ROOTFS_RO_UNNEEDED` variable. I was indeed building the image a read-only but still needed `update-rc.d` to make runtime modifications to some services while temporarily mounting the rootfs on my development target as RW.

Adding `ROOTFS_RO_UNNEEDED:remove = " update-rc.d"` to the development version of my image resolved the problem.